# Нужен таймер для прогресс-бара

Tags: java, android

Всем привет,делаю проект под названием "тамагочи".
Нужна ваша помощь с таймером для прогресс-бара. Суть в том что при обнулении таймера, у прогресс бара должна уменьшаться полоска до определенного места,задерживаться там на какое-то время,и дальше уменьшаться пока не достигнет конца.

P.s. сам прогресс бар есть в разметке.

```
package com.triastudios.finalapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Timer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements Serializable {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: setProgress() — устанавливает заданное значение индикатора прогресса;

Comment: Не очень понятно зачем вы в вопросе привели код, который ничего не делает. К тому же AsyncTask тут - не лучшее решение. По идее, вам надо как-то так сделать: создать повторяющуюся задачу. Например через TimerTask. При срабатывании задачи, например, анимировать значение прогресса (например через ObjectAnimator). В первом приближении получится то, что как мне кажется, вам нужно.